# Converting a 2x2km point grid to a coincident 1x1km grid

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I needed to convert a 2x2km point grid (specifically the [LUCAS grid](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/lucas/data/lucas-grid)) into a coincident 1x1km grid.

Is there a "simple" way of doing this in QGIS?

Comment: What is the advance over using corine landcover which available as a raster? Does the dataset contain multiple attributes?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about Corine, but I wanted to use this point grid primarily for the selection of sampling areas, and only secondarily to explore it's information on land cover.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Comment: Any other input on how to address this issue? Thanks, Rui.